# JQuery Countdown Plugin (by Keith Wood) does not work on chrome Version 24.0.1312.52

Tags: jquery, countdown

I have been using the jQuery Countdown Plugin by Keith Wood and it has been working absolutely fine up till Chrome version 23. However, I recently upgraded my browser to version 24.0.1312.52, now the timer has stopped updating. Instead, the time is refreshed only on page refresh.

The same plugin is working fine on IE 8/9, FF (latest version).

Is anyone else facing this problem?

I visited the plugin's home page, but there the timer is working absolutely fine.

Comment: if it works on demo page, then something different in your code. What errors are thrown? Create demo in  jsfiddle.net that replicates the problem. WIthout code to replicate nobody can help

Comment: Press F12 and go to the console tab.  Are there any errors that will help identify your problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ck8ab/

few of the css are used for internal purpose just to beautify the display. the rest of the code logic is as such. The jquery.countdown.js file can be assumed to be present as it is there in my code. jquery version is 1.7.2 It was working fine in chrome v23. I didn't change code, but updated my browser.

Comment: @Archer there were no error logs. I verified that.

Comment: I got the exact same problem. Everything worked find and know the countdown remains static.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure you're using verion 1.6.1 of the Countdown plugin.

Comment: It's a very good answer. I had the same problem and I didn't update to this late version. Now it works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with firefox version 23. I updated Countdown plugin to version 1.6.3 and it works fine now.

You can download from here: [JQuery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)

Answer (score 1):

I changed from minified version of the script (jquery.countdown.min.js) to normal version (jquery.countdown.js) and the countdown started. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Scratch that! I just updated to version 1.6.2 and it works fine now.

Comment: Some more detail on which versions of the plugin work with which versions of Chrome is probably necessary to make this a helpful answer. The accepted answer already suggested using 1.6.1; did that work for you, or not?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My countdown didn't work at all on any browser. Loading the plugin script before the countdown script seemed to solve my problem.